# UI Canvas Start - Quit Game

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have 2 Canvas UIs `(Start and Exit)` on the home screen of my game. I want to add 1 script that does the following:

When the UI Image `Play` is clicked

```
public void NextLevel(int level)
{
    Score.Inicializar(); 
    Application.LoadLevel (1);

}
```

When the UI Image `Exit` is clicked

`Application.Quit ()`;

C# if possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate? The question is a bit unclear

Comment: Something to note is that Application.LoadLevel(int level) is deprecated, use the LevelManager and load the level. What I'm getting from the question is that you have 2 canvases and you want a script to load the next level of the current level? And another function called `exit` that does Application.quit() ?

Comment: @AndrewL yes when that UI clicked Play = LoadLevel / Exit = Application Quit.

Comment: You could create a script that checks if the play or exit button is clicked but I would create two, an exit script and a play script

Comment: What is the platform you are using? For instance, Quit does not kill the app on iOS, it just pauses it.

Comment: @Everts that is for Android =]

Comment: When building for mobile application, it is recommended not to offer such possibility. The user is used to press the home button from the OS to close an app. You should leave it like this.

Comment: @Everts, thats buttons is for MAIN scene =] ...

Comment: hi @AlanVieiraRezende - do you understand how to simply use UI.Button ?  you just drag a function to the slot down the bottom of the Button in inspector.

Comment: @JoeBlow yeah, now. I have 2 option, use Code Below from Behnam, or this way.  Creat > UI > Button / At Button Script (Inspector)  add On Click ()  / Drag Script / Select what you want =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this script to your Play image:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
//using UnityEngine.SceneManagement; // uncomment this line in case you wanna use SceneManager

public class HandleClickOnPlayImage : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler {
    int level = 1; // I'm assuming you're setting this value somehow in your application

    public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Score.Inicializar(); 
        Application.LoadLevel (level);
        // SceneManager.LoadScene (level); // <-- use this method instead for loading scenes
    }   
}
```

And add this script to your Exit image:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class HandleClickOnExitImage : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler {
    public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }   
}
```

And finally make sure no other ui blocking/overlapping your images, otherwise they won't receive any click event.

Not to mention that a script file's name should match the name of it class :)

Comment: Try using the `SceneManager.LoadScene()` , because `Application.LoadLevel()` is deprecated.

Comment: Changed!!! For future ... dont forget `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;` for `Scenemanager.LoadScene()` work