# UI Canvas Image with UI Buttons

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have UI canvas image with 2 UI buttons. I set as background, that layer. But this layer overlaying my game! How do I it is behind everything?

[image]
[image]

I want set the second imagem as background.

I am using the UI Canvas because it automatically adjusts to any screen through the anchors.

-

Comment: Just by reading your last question before this one, I want to tell you that the way you are doing your UI is bad. Even though the last question has been answered, the answer is wrong too. It may be working for you now, but you will have lots of problems when your UI gets bigger. Please expand every UI GameObject in your scene, take Screen shot,then post a picture of the hierarchy of your UI GameObject. I will show you how to do this properly

Comment: I am in the process of writing this. I have few more questions. Is the background you want  to set called "Backgound" that is under cameraBackground->Canvas? Also which gameObjects in your scene are the Jump, Ground, Joystick,Score and pause button under? Some of these are named in Spanish and I don't speak Spanish....

Comment: Updated with translate =] my Background IS Background (inside Canvas) - Bee are the player =] that litle bee in midle first screen =] -

Comment: Ok,I will try now, was sleeping in the last 2 hours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No GameObject in your scene should be under Canvas unless the GameObject is part of the UI. The background image you want to use is not a UI. Your post shows that you only want it as a UI because Canvas automatically adjust the size to match the screen size.

How to fix this with code and without making that background texture part of the UI.

1.**Remove/Delete** the current Background and the Canvas Object for it. You don't need it.

2.**Re-import** the background image and make sure that its **Texture Type** is set to **Sprite (2D and UI)**

3.Drag it to the scene and rename it to **Background**. Now put it under **Bee** **GameObject**. **Bee** should now be the **parent** of the **Background** texture and the Background texture should be on top of **Ground** Object.

4.Create a script called `BackGroundResizer` and put the code below in it. Attach the script to the **Background** GameObject/Texture.

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
 resizeSprite();
}

void resizeSprite()
{
 SpriteRenderer bgSprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
 float screenHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize * 2;
 float screenWidth = screenHeight / Screen.height * Screen.width;
 transform.localScale = new Vector3(screenWidth / bgSprite.sprite.bounds.size.x,   screenHeight / bgSprite.sprite.bounds.size.y, 1);
}
```

This should solve your current problem for this post. Below describes how to properly setup a UI.

Use different Canvas to **separate** your UI and group them depending on when they are displayed. Then you can toggle the whole Canvas **on**/**off**. Your [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806531/ui-canvas-start-quit-game) before this post shows that you are using image as button and you have a different script attached to two images you are using as buttons. Use **Buttons** for **buttons** and **image** for **non-clickable** objects. Simple as that. So change those images to buttons.

You don't need the GameOver scene. A GameOverCanvas is fine.
The GameObjects in bold are the **parent** Objects(Canvas). The ones under that starts with '**-**' are the **child** GameObjects.

**Step 1:**

Create `Canvas` and name it **MainMenuCanvas** (First UI to display when game Loads).Create each child button and rename them as below(**GameObject->UI->Button**):

```
-playButton;
-settingsButton;
-exitGameButton;
```

Attach the [MainMenuCanvas script](http://pastebin.com/tw1kKKVG) to the **MainMenuCanvas** Object.

**Step 2:**

Create a `Canvas` and name it **GameCanvas** (Displayed during game).Create each child button and rename them as below(**GameObject->UI->Button**):

```
-pauseButton
-jumpButton
```

Attach the [GameCanvas script](http://pastebin.com/C3WSzMQq) to the **GameCanvas** Object.

**Step 3:**

Create a `Canvas` and name it **PauseCanvas** (Displayed when pause button is clicked).Create each child button and rename them as below(**GameObject->UI->Button**):

```
-resumeButton;
-backToMainMenuButton;
-settingsButton;
-exitGameButton;
```

Attach the [PauseCanvas script](http://pastebin.com/czSQtcCi) to the **PauseCanvas** Object.

**Step 4:**

Create a `Canvas` and name it **SettingsCanvas** (Displayed when settings button is clicked).Create each child button and rename them as below(**GameObject->UI->Button**):

```
-backButton;
```

Attach the [SettingsCanvas script](http://pastebin.com/mi05Jnmk) to the **SettingsCanvas** Object.

**Step 5:**

Create a `Canvas` and name it **GameOverCanvas** (Displayed when Game is Over or player is killed).Create each child button and rename them as below(**GameObject->UI->Button**):

```
-playAgainButton;
-backToMainMenuButton;
-exitGameButton;
```

Attach the [GameOverCanvas script](http://pastebin.com/jsPzNA17) to the **GameOverCanvas** Object.

**Step 6:**

In the **Game** scene, make sure that only **GameCanvas** is enabled. The rest of the canvas should be manually **disabled**.

**Step 7:**

In the **Menu** scene, make sure that only **MainMenuCanvas** is enabled. The rest of the canvas should be manually **disabled**.

Once you get this setup correctly, the UI code templates I provided should work. No more UI **overlapping** each other and you can easily add or remove features.

Your setup should look like the image below.

[image]

Comment: I will update how to setup your UI later on but this should solve your current problem.

Comment: It does not work when the aspect ratio is changed, not to change background image proportionally.

Comment: @AlanVieiraRezende That's because the screen size does not change during play on Android and iOS.  Although it can change in the Editor. Try this on Android or iOS, it should work as expected. If you want it to change in the Editor while you are re-sizing it in the game-view, put `resizeSprite();` in the `Update()` function instead of `Start()` function. Now it should resize-anytime in the game-view. Although you don't have to do this in the mobile devices as it will do it once in the start function. Let me know ...

Comment: @AlanVieiraRezende Also updated my post to show how to setup your UI.

Comment: Hello I was away from home, just come, I will try and warn you if it worked! =]

Comment: I was talking to my wife about how you were helping me with my game when I got home today and read to code immediately understood how it would work and I realized that was exactly what I wanted. I do not know how to thank you, neither can understand what led you to give me this script so perfect, really pray to God that he bless you because you helped me a priceless way! Thank you!!!

Comment: @AlanVieiraRezende You are welcome. Good luck with your game. Your first game may not be perfect as that's what usually happens to beginners but you learn from it and get better/improve. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you look into using a separate UI camera. This will allow you to draw only the UI to the second camera and not the Main Camera. You can then Draw that at whatever depth you want relative to everything else. To do this you will have to create another camera and set it's `Culling Mask` and `Clear Flags` to only draw the UI and not a skybox.

If you google 'UI camera Unity' there should be a lot more information on doing exactly what you want. This is a relatively common thing to do.

Comment: I need drag and drop all UI canvas into this new camera?

Comment: No, keep the UI canvas separate. You need to set the new camera's `Culling Mask` so that only 'UI' is ticked. Then untick 'UI' in the `Main Camera`'s culling mask. You will then have on camera drawing the UI and another drawing everything else.

Comment: Now that you have updated your answer with screen shots, I think the other answer has understood your individual problem much better and gives a fuller answer. Follow that.